# How to use SORT options?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I take data from `ngrx-store`

```
getData$: Observable<IGetData>;

this.getData$ = this.store.select(
      fromStore.dataSelector.getNewData,
    );

// array example [
{id: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number},
{id: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number},
{id: number, name: string, btn: number, index: number}
]
```

And in HTML I use this in `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let data of getData$ | async">
  <div>{{data.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I want to `orderby` this by `ID` direct in component because orderBy `PIPE` directly in view is not recommendation.

I try this but I get error `Property 'sort' does not exist on type`

```
// descending
this.getData$.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id); 

//ascending
this.getData$.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

How to use in this case `SORT` options?

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

I don't use angular, so I'm not sure of the answer. But it looks like your data is not array. I had similar issue with some data from MongoDB where even it was an array it was passed as an object. 
You can try wrapping data in `Array.from()` like `Array.from(this.getData$).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)`

You can also verify the type of data to make sure it's an array. `console.log((typeof((a, b) => a.id - b.id))`

Comment: Thnx, i will try

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [ngrx effets](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#comparison-with-component-based-side-effects). Since your `getData$` is an `Observable` and not an `Array` you can try something like this:

```
this.getData$ = this.getData$
  .pipe(
     map((data) => data.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id))
  );
```

Although I have never worked with ngrx, I have found something in the docs for manipulating (sorting your entities) the proper way ([ngrx adapter](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter)).

Comment: Thnx, I will try

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where did you see that `PIPE` is not recommended. But in your case, you can: Use an Angular pipe, or modify your Observable like this:

```js
this.getData$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromStore.dataSelector.getNewData),
  map(data => [...data].sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)),
);
```

`sort` modify the array, so you should make a copy of it with `[...data]`

Comment: Hi, thnx i will try. Here is info about orderBy and Sort PIPE... i took only about this kind od PIPE, not another....https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: OK, what they said is that they do not provide a generic pipe using property name as variable, which is bad. You can use a pure pipe without any problem with performance / minification.